# Data not being past to view controller with prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a segue which when fired should have some data sent with it, so i have the below method set up:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *proFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleProTap:)];
    [self.sharePost addGestureRecognizer:proFingerTap];
...
}
- (void)handleProTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profileToPost" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"profileToPost"]) {
        ProPostViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"name:%@ id:%ld",_profileName,(long)_profileid]);

        destViewController.profileid = _profileid;
        destViewController.profileName = _profileName;
    }
}
```

in the deist view controller i have the below in the header file:

```
@interface ProPostViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>{
    NSInteger profileid;
    NSString *profileName;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger profileid;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *profileName;
```

and then:

@implementation ProPostViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"name:%@ id:%ld",profileName,(long)profileid]);
    if (profileid != 0){
        [_postTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posting to %@",profileName]];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

However the code is not passing the data as it should, from the two NSLogs which take place during this i get:

```
2015-08-11 10:48:53.653 APP[1705:119528] name:Alex id:3
2015-08-11 10:48:53.685 APP[1705:119528] name:(null) id:0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `viewDidLoad`, change this line:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"name:%@ id:%ld",profileName,(long)profileid]);
```

to this:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"name:%@ id:%ld",self.profileName,(long)self.profileid]);
```

And if that works, get rid of the `profileName` and `profileid` ivars and leave the properties in place.  If the compiler complains, use `@synthesize` for the two properties.